# While Loop with LCV of cin won't exit in C++

Tags: c++, while-loop, exit, cin

This is hw. I have asked my professor why the following code won't exit the while loop, and he/she couldn't tell me. My understanding is that once the input stream has no more values to read, the cin will return a value of false, and should cause the while loop to exit. Mine does not. It seems to keep read the input values (a set of integers) process through the loop, then wait for more input. Can anyone tell me why? Below is the code.

```
# include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int iEvenSum = 0;
int iOddSum = 0;
int iNum;

// prompt user
cout << "Input any set of integers, separated by a space:\n";
cin >> iNum;
cout << "You input: ";

while (cin)
{
    cout << iNum << " ";

    if (iNum % 2 == 0)
        iEvenSum = iEvenSum + iNum;
    else
        iOddSum = iOddSum + iNum;

    cin >> iNum;
}

cout << "\n\nThe sum of Even numbers is " << iEvenSum << "." << endl;
cout << "The sum of Odd numbers is " << iOddSum << "." << endl;

return 0;

}
```

Comment: what did you try to make the loop stop? Simply stop providing input will not change anything: `cin` just waits for another input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`while(cin)` remains true as long as the `cin` stream is ok and becomes false if `cin` encounters an end of file character or an error.

In your case, `while(cin)` will keep on reading the numbers until it encounters an `EOF` character or an error. Type `Ctrl-D` when you don't have any more input numbers and it should quit the `while` loop

Comment: Thank you both for the input. That makes a lot more sense. So if I prompt the user to end their set of integers with anything other than an integer, it will act as a EOF because it won't store in the int variable, causing an error or false (in a crude way of course).

Comment: @user2888226 Yes, exactly.